# What are the differences between pjax and djax ? jQuery

Tags: ajax, pjax

I'm completely new to this terms but I didn't understand what the differences between them or, maybe it's just misunderstanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PJAX is "[pushState + AJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)", and DJAX is "[Dynamic PJAX](https://github.com/beezee/djax)".